# Do not show div if props doesn't have values

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have the following component

```
<template>
  <div class="pt-20 pb-4 px-6 xl:px-40 bg-theme-primary">
    <div class="text-center mb-24">
      <h1 class="text-xl lg:text-2xl uppercase font-bold mb-2">{{ mainTitle }}</h1>
      <p class="text-base">{{ mainText }}</p>
    </div>

    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "FeaturesWGrid",
  props: {
    mainTitle: String,
    mainText: String
  }
};
</script>
```

and the following implementation

```
<FeaturesWGrid>
  <Grid>
    <div class="bg-theme-secondary rounded py-4 px-12">
      <h2 class="text-xl font-medium mb-6">General</h2>
      <Accordion question="Start a live chat" answer="24/7" />
      <Accordion question="Start a live chat" answer="24/7" />
      <Accordion question="Start a live chat" answer="24/7" />
      <Accordion question="Start a live chat" answer="24/7" />
      <Accordion question="Start a live chat" answer="24/7" />
    </div>
  </Grid>
</FeaturesWGrid>
```

This is just dummy content for now, however, my issue for this section I don't need to add a `mainTitle` and `mainText` is it possible to hide the `<div class="text-center mb-24">` if the props don't have any values.

Comment: You could combine the [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) pseudo-class with `display: none` (be mindful of browser support), and conditionally display your `h1` and `p` if they have content. I'm not a Vue user but I suspect such a pattern exists.

Answer (score 1):

Use v-if or v-show (if you wish to leave div just hidden)

```
<div class="text-center mb-24" v-if="mainTitle && mainText">
```

Comment: Tried this solution, it doesn't hide the div

Comment: The condition seems to be opposite the requested functionality: it *shows* the `div` only if both fields are empty. It should be `v-if="mainTitle && mainText"`.